# how to use datepart with date in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on an sql query where i want to attach datepart with time part. in the time part minute will be 20,40,59. and second will be always 00. For this i used the following query: Because i have report of only 20 minute of duration like 0-20 minute, 21-40 minute, and 41-59 minute of any hour.

```
DECLARE @RandomDate datetime
DECLARE @HH INT
DECLARE @MM INT
DECLARE @S INT=00


SELECT    @RandomDate=
DATEADD(day,ROUND(DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),GETDATE())*(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 5),
DATEADD(second, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 48000, GETDATE())) 


SELECT @HH= DATEPART(hour,@RandomDate),@MM=DATEPART(MINUTE,@RandomDate)


SELECT  @RandomDate,@HH,@MM,@S


SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@RandomDate)+ 
DATEPART(hour,@RandomDate)+DATEPART(MINUTE,@RandomDate)+00
```

But it is showing error as

```
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

at the position

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@RandomDate)+ 
DATEPART(hour,@RandomDate)+DATEPART(MINUTE,@RandomDate)+00
```

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting? Can you add some sample output to the Question?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. You'll need to construct the date in string parts to do what you're after. Also, note that `+00` is the same as `+0` (an integer does not retain leading zeroes in SQL Server).

Comment: Suppose the Date is 2018-04-24, hour is 16,min is 20, then output should be 2018-04-24 16:20:00. I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: So you just want to remove the seconds part?

Comment: I want to add the second part that is time part in form of hour, minute and second in individual variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add hours and minutes to the date variable as minutes

```
SELECT dateadd(mi, @HH * 60 + @MM, convert(datetime, convert(date,@RandomDate)))
```

Comment: IT IS WORKING FINE FOR ME

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the seconds part of the `DateTime` value, you can do it much simpler using `DATEADD` and `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(Second, -DATEPART(Second, @RandomDate), @RandomDate)
```

If you want to set the time portion of the `DateTime` from individual parts representing hours, minutes and seconds, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, @HH, 
           DATEADD(MINUTE, @MM, 
               DATEADD(SECOND, @S, CAST(CAST(@RandomDate As Date) As DateTime))
           )
       )
```

The double cast to `date` and back to `datetime` truncates the original time portion to 00:00:00, and the DATEADD adds the individual values to the datetime.

Comment: IT WORKS GOOD FOR ME

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(FORMAT(@RandomDate, N'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm') AS DATETIME)
```

Updated...

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @RandomDate, 120) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: That will return a string, and also the `Format` built in function was introduced in 2012 version. the OP is working with 2008.